# Simple Averaging Program Not Getting Calculated Results

Tags: java

When ran the results are as if values were not entered.
I was hoping someone or all could review code and critique.

```
package practice_array_tables;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Practice_Array_Tables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     //Variables
        String Principal, Rate, Time;

        //Prompt user for input via JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        Principal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter Principle Amount. ");

          //Enter Rate.
        Rate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter Rate, i.e 0.10 ");

        //Enter Time
        Time = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter Time ");

        //Parse String to Int.
        int p = Integer.parseInt(Principal);
        int r = Integer.parseInt(Rate);
        int t = Integer.parseInt(Time);

        //Compute Compound Interest.\
       double CompoundInterest = p * Math.pow((1+r / 100), t );
       double c = CompoundInterest;

       //Print results to JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " your answer " + c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

why do you make a double, and then assign that same double to a new double?
I also think your formula for compound interest is wrong on top of that.
A=P(1+(r/n))^nt

Furthermore, you're parsing Rate into an int, effectively making it 0. You should parse it to a double. Specifically look at these two lines (not consecutive)

```
Rate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter Rate, i.e 0.10 ");
int r = Integer.parseInt(Rate);
```

If you look in the java API under the Double class, you'll find a parseDouble method very similar to the parseInt.
Simply do

```
double r = Double.parseDouble(Rate);
```

this will give you what you expect; a number with a decimal. I suspect your problem probably arises from multiplying by 0.

Comment: You can add more to make this an effective answer. Instead of just pointing out what is wrong, also show how to fix it.